# Multimedia links to pdfs in RTF are not working for some

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1, rtf, multimedia, binary

I have the following source code in the RTF, when I publish the page only last 2 links are working (tcm:5-283068,tcm:5-283067). When I looked at the file server only the last documents are deployed. Also I noticed that If I put tcm:5-283070,tcm:5-283069 on one component and tcm:5-283068,tcm:5-283067 on another component, all of the links are working. Is there any limit on binary links at component level for publishing or deploying?

```
<p><a href="tcm:5-283070" title="Older women’s experience of breast cancer       alongside other health conditions: The EPAN study of women aged 70 years and   over" target="_blank">Download the summary [test]</a>.</p> 
<p><a href="tcm:5-283069" title="Identifying the impact of service user involvement on the lives of people affected by cancer" target="_blank">Download the summary [test]</a>.</p>
<p><a href="tcm:5-283068" title="Supporting relatives: An investigation into   obstacles and aids to information exchange within families affected by cancer"   target="_blank">Download the summary [test]</a>.</p>
<p><a href="tcm:5-283067" title="The use of herbal medicines by people with cancer" target="_blank">Download the summary [test]</a>.</p>
```

Thanks,
Suneetha

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Also I noticed that If I put tcm:5-283070,tcm:5-283069 on one component and tcm:5-283068,tcm:5-283067 on another component, all of the links are working." please?

Comment: I suspect you mean that when there are 4 links only the first 2 show, but when you use a copy of the same compoent and have two links each in the links appear fine - in which case, can you confirm what happens when there's *1* or *3* links (just out of interest). There is no limit in the out of the box ResolveXHTML method with regards the quantity of links that can be resolved; are you sure your code isn't set to only read the first two links? Perhaps add the section of code that you have used to render the RTFs

Comment: There is no limit on publishing linked binaries from a Component or Page, so I would check in the Template Builder what happens with these binaries, is the binary links are correctly resolved etc.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this may because your HTML isn't valid (due to the spurious `over` text in your code example).

[image]

This will be preventing the templating code from adding the PDF to the deployment package.

Can you try updating the code and re-publishing.

P.S. If the items failed to publish due to size, then you would see this as `Failed` in the Publishing Queue.

Comment: sorry it was my mistake while copy and pasting. The html was correct.

Comment: Ah, ok. Then please ignore my answer!

Comment: <p><a href="tcm:5-283070" title="Older women’s experience of breast cancer alongside other health conditions: The EPAN study of women aged 70 years and over" target="_blank">Download the summary [test]</a>.</p><p><a href="tcm:5-283069" title="Identifying the impact of service user involvement on the lives of people affected by cancer" target="_blank">Download the summary [test]</a>.</p><p><a href="tcm:5-283068" title="Supporting relatives: An investigation into obstacles and aids to information exchange within families affected by cancer" target="_blank">Download the summary [test]</a>.</p>

Comment: this is actual code

Comment: Please edit it in the question instead of posting in the comments...